# Can't import createElement into lightning web component

Tags: lightning-web-components, import

I have this custom lightning web component

```
import {LightningElement, api, createElement } from 'lwc';

export default class Tm_customLWCGenerator extends LightningElement {

}
```

And when I try to save and deploy to org it gives me the following error:

**Error 57  [Line: 1, Col: 13] LWC1518: Invalid LWC imported identifier "createElement"**

This is my meta.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<apiVersion>46</apiVersion>
<description>Generates custom lightning web component based on componentName, componentClass and api variables</description>
<masterLabel>masterLabelForLWC</masterLabel>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Is there something that I'm doing wrong? Cause I see many references using this `createElement` but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR: you can't use `createElement` on the Salesforce Platform.**

Dynamic component creation isn't available in Lightning Web Component on the Salesforce Platform, mostly for performance reasons.
You can get more details from a team architect [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244847/not-able-to-render-dynamic-lightning-web-component).

There is a RFC for it [here](https://github.com/salesforce/lwc-rfcs/blob/master/text/0000-dynamic-components.md), and discussions about potential implementation has started [here](https://github.com/salesforce/lwc-rfcs/pull/10).

Comment: Thanks! I'll go for a custom approach then.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

import { createElement } from 'lwc';

export default class Tm_customLWCGenerator extends LightningElement {

}

This looks weird but it works.