# div innerHTML with standard lightning web components

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, dom

I'm trying to display a custom format for my lightning web component via rendered and innerHTML of a div.

```
<template>
    <div class="container" lwc:dom="manual"></div>
</template>
```

js (data has @track):

```
renderedCallback() {
    if(this.data){
        const container = this.template.querySelector('.container'); 
        container.innerHTML = '<lightning-input name="test" value="' + this.data.societyID + '"></lightning-input>';
    }
}
```

But it's giving me no errors but also not displaying anything on my div. Is innerHTML only available for native HTML or is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7):

You **cannot** create/use innerHTML for custom components (`c` or `lightning` namespace) in LWC but you can do so for native elements. Below is the detailed explanation.

`lightning-input` is [Customized built-in element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements). So, you can logically (but does not work) use [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

> Customized built-in elements inherit from basic HTML elements. To
>   create one of these, you have to specify which element they extend (as
>   implied in the examples above), and they are used by writing out the
>   basic element but specifying the name of the custom element in the is
>   attribute (or property). For example , or
>   document.createElement("p", { is: "word-count" }).

Sample:

```
<lightning-input></lightning-input>
<lightning-button label="Add Input" onclick={addInput}></lightning-button>
<div lwc:dom="manual" class="container"></div>
```

JS:

```
addInput() {
    let linput = document.createElement('lightning-input', { is: 'lightning-input' });
    this.template.querySelector('.container').appendChild(linput);
}
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

> ### Why it does not work?
>
> Although you are able to create lightning input element and add it
>   in DOM inside `div.container` as shown in screenshot above, it will be
>   missing the main content like **span, label, input** - it will not
>   render. The custom lightning elements are designed and defined in such a way. For createElement to work, salesforce should release such
>   native lightning API - you can check this answer -
>   [Not able to render dynamic Lightning Web Component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244847/not-able-to-render-dynamic-lightning-web-component)
>   from Software Architect at Salesforce (Lightning Platform).

---

And yes native elements can be created. For example change JS to below will work:

```
addInput() {
    let linput = document.createElement('input');
    this.template.querySelector('.container').appendChild(linput);
}
```