# Replace href in html when displaying with lightning-formatted-rich-text

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a custom LWC on Case record pages that displays related Knowledge Base articles based on record field values. The KB articles are long and complex and contain a number of anchor tags that link to headers within the articles. I perform a server-side query in Apex to get the article info, then display the article text on title click with lightning-formatted-rich-text.

The embedded anchor tags caused a page reload when clicked, which then did not scroll to the appropriate article header because the article text is hidden on load. I implemented sfdcfox's excellent answer to [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/256007/how-do-you-define-an-element-with-an-id-attribute-using-lwc) to resolve the reloading issue (I change the contents of the anchor tags in my server-side code). However, now clicking on the links does nothing because lightning-formatted-rich-text strips out all HTML attributes that are not whitelisted, and onclick is not on the whitelist. I can't change the anchor tags to any built-in lightning components because none of those are whitelisted either.

It seems like there might be a javascript or html way to get around this limitation, but I just don't know enough about those languages to figure it out. Is there any way to display HTML within an LWC other than the lightning-formatted-rich-text component? Any other way to get around this issue? I wouldn't mind re-writing this as an aura component if there were a way to achieve it there.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

**Apex Class**

```
public with sharing class KbSearchController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=false)
    public static List<KbSuggestionResult> suggest(String searchText){
        List<KbSuggestionResult> returnVal = new List<KbSuggestionResult>();

        try {
            searchText = searchText.replaceAll(',', ' OR ');

            String sosl = 'FIND \'' + searchText + '\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING General__kav(id, title, summary, Description__c, LastPublishedDate WHERE PublishStatus = \'Online\' AND Language = \'en_US\') WITH SNIPPET (target_length=120)';
            Search.SearchResults searchResults = Search.find(sosl);
            List<Search.SearchResult> articlelist = searchResults.get('General__kav');

            for (Search.SearchResult searchResult : articleList) { 
                General__kav article = (General__kav) searchResult.getSObject(); 

                KbSuggestionResult suggestion = new KbSuggestionResult();
                suggestion.id = article.Id;
                suggestion.title = article.Title;
                suggestion.summary = article.Summary;
                suggestion.description = sanitizeDescription(article.Description__c);//.unescapeHtml4()
                suggestion.lastpub = article.LastPublishedDate;

                returnVal.add(suggestion);
            } 
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.debug('KbSearchController.suggest.error: ' + ex);
        }

        return returnVal;
    }


    private static string sanitizeDescription(string d) {
        d = d.replace('<a id="Travel-and-lifestyle-benefits-process" name="Travel-and-lifestyle-benefits-process">', '<a data-target-id="Travel-and-lifestyle-benefits-process" name="Travel-and-lifestyle-benefits-process">');
        d = d.replace('<a href="#Travel-and-lifestyle-benefits-process">', '<a href="javascript:void()" data-id="Travel-and-lifestyle-benefits-process" onclick={navToAnchor}>');
        // these items are hard-coded now for the POC, but will eventually be replaced with regex
        return d;
    }


    public class KbSuggestionResult{
        @AuraEnabled
        public string id { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public string title { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public string summary { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public string description { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public datetime lastpub { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**LWC .cmp**

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Knowledge" icon-name="standard:knowledge" class="slds-p-around_small">
        <ul class="slds-m-top_x-small">
            <template for:each={suggestedArticles} for:item="suggestedArticle">
                <lightning-layout-item key={suggestedArticle.id} flexibility="auto">
                        <div onclick={handleView} data-value={suggestedArticle.id}>
                            <h1 slot="title" class="itemTitle textUnderline slds-truncate">
                                <lightning-button 
                                    label={suggestedArticle.title}
                                    variant="base">
                                </lightning-button>
                            </h1>
                            <div class="slds-tile__detail slds-text-body--small slds-var-p-bottom_xxx-small articleMetaData">
                                <span class="slds-text-color_weak"> Last Published&nbsp; 
                                    <lightning-formatted-date-time 
                                        value={suggestedArticle.lastpub} 
                                        year="numeric" 
                                        month="short" 
                                        day="numeric" 
                                        hour="numeric"
                                        minute="numeric">
                                    </lightning-formatted-date-time>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="resultBody">
                                {suggestedArticle.summary}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <p if:true={suggestedArticle.show} class="slds-p-horizontal_small">
                            <lightning-formatted-rich-text value={suggestedArticle.description}></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
                        </p>
                        <p slot="footer"></p>
                </lightning-layout-item>
            </template>
        </ul>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**LWC .js**

```js
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { registerListener, unregisterAllListeners, fireEvent } from 'c/pubsub';
import suggest from '@salesforce/apex/KbSearchController.suggest';

export default class KbSearch extends LightningElement {
    @track suggestedArticles = [];
    @wire(CurrentPageReference) pageRef;    

    connectedCallback() {
        registerListener('kbSearchChange', this.handleSearchChange, this);
    }

    disconnectedCallback() {
        unregisterAllListeners(this);
    }

    handleSearchChange(searchText){
        suggest({searchText: searchText})
            .then(data => {
                this.suggestedArticles = data;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('errors retrieving kb search data: ' + error);
            });
    }

    handleView(event){
        let articleId = event.currentTarget.dataset.value;
        if( articleId != null){
            this.suggestedArticles.forEach(article => {
                if(article.id == articleId){
                    console.log(article.description);
                    article.show = !article.show;
                } else{
                    article.show = false;
                }
            })
        }
    }

    navToAnchor(event) {
        let targetId = event.target.dataset.targetId;
        let target = this.template.querySelector(`[data-id="${targetId}"]`);
        target.scrollIntoView();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm none too confident that you can solve this.  `lightning-formatted-rich-text` is a proprietary component whose restrictions probably can't be worked around.  And LWC still locks down many forms DOM manipulation that would be needed to render the rich text any other way.  If there's an answer, it might be something along the lines of using `lwc:dom="manual"` ... see this thread: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/279945/div-innerhtml-with-standard-lightning-web-components