# aura:dependency migration to lightning web component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

what would be the equivalent to
`<aura:dependency resource="c:lightningComponent" />`
in Lightning Web components?

I wonder if importing the class that holds the component logic would suffice ? please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

`aura:dependency` is used when you are dynamically creating components in javascript of aura or lightning out . Now LWC does not support [dynamic component creation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/243876/dynamic-component-creation-in-lightning-web-components) or lightning out so I believe as of now there is no need of LWC equivalent of `aura: dependency`