# LWC - Send Property Down to Dynamically Created Template

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have created a small app in LWC where different templates are shown by following [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/243884/49715). The flipping of the templates works fine, but there doesn't appear to be an obvious way to send data down the hierarchy when changing the template.

Assuming you have a main component:

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";
import loadingTemplate from "./loading.html";
import finalTemplate from "./fancyTemplate.html";

export default class HelloWorld extends LightningElement {
    @track isLoading = true;
    @track recordId;

    render() {
        return this.isLoading ? loadingTemplate : finalTemplate;
    }
}
```

And `loadingTemplate` retrieves a recordId and sends it up to the main component through an event, which then gets bound to the `recordId` seen above.

How can I send the value of `recordId` down to `finalTemplate` upon generation? I can certainly do it with using a series of `<div if:true{something}>` elements, but feel this is something better suited for the JS to handle.

Comment: your link "this answer" is navigating to "http://components". Can you correct it

Comment: @salesforce-sas thanks for the catch - didn't realize the url got janked up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since both templates - `loading` and `fancyTemplate` will be in same folder, they will be binded to the same js file explicitly. You, as a developer need not do anything. When `recordId` changes, it will automatically update in all templates when they load.

**[Here is the playground example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/Yuz9pX4PG/2/edit)**

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import custom1 from "./custom1.html";
import custom2 from "./custom2.html";

export default class App extends LightningElement {
    @track isLoading = true;
    @track recordId;

    render() {
        return this.isLoading ? custom1 : custom2;
    }

    setRecordId = () => this.recordId = 'XXX123123';
    loadingDone = () => this.isLoading = false;
}
```

When you click on **Set Record Id** and then on **Loading Done** to mimic the server call, you will see the new value in new template `custom2.html` when it loads.