# Parse string to HTML in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am having a template like this

### HMTL

```
<template>
    <lightning-tabset>
        <lightning-tab>
            {dynamicComponent}
        </lightning-tab>
    </lightning-tabset>
</template>
```

### JS

```
@track dynamicComponent='<c-load-child></c-load-child>';
```

but it is just rendering as string only but i need it to render as HTML. I tried many option with innerHTMl,appendchild but nothing is working.

Comment: No. Actually it will just display the HTML string in the browser but my requirement is parse the string and render whatever HTML is there inside that `<c-load-child>`. I am having three text box inside that component and i want it to get render in browser

Comment: As far as I know you can switch templates dynamically but not introduce them dynamically.

Comment: @SFDC-Beginner you cannot dynamically add sub-components this way, only HTML. LWCs are specifically "compiled" and templates are not actually simple HTML but rather are converted in to a specific load of JavaScript by the "LWC compiler".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic component creation in Lightning Web Components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/243876/dynamic-component-creation-in-lightning-web-components)