# LWC.CreateElement?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom, dom

I was researching for `document.createElement()` and could not seem to find anything. Is there any way where I can use `createElement` in salesforce or any other Alternative as I need to create div dynamically.

Comment: This can help - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/243876/dynamic-component-creation-in-lightning-web-components

Comment: Do explain why this markup approach won't work for your case`<div if:true={flag} ...></div>`.

Comment: This is an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info). Please explain what you're trying to do so that we can help you better.

Comment: Check this one - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244847/not-able-to-render-dynamic-lightning-web-component

Comment: @sfdcfox I want to create a account hierarchy tree where I can drag and drop the account which will change the account hierarchy accordingly. My approach was to create dynamic divs for each account which will then give me flexibility to work around them.